# とか and など in same sentence

Tags: particles

This sentence includes both とか and など.

> 金魚の食べ物は虫とか水草などです。

Is there a difference in meaning between the two? Is there a reason to use both like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 「AとかBなど」+ です・だ・が・を・に etc.
>   ("A and/or B, etc.", "things like A and B")

Both of とか and など are used to give examples. とか is more colloquial/conversational than など.

You can also use:

> 「AやBなど」+ です・だ・が・を・に etc.
>   「AとかBとか」+ です・だ・が・を・に etc. ← casual
>   「AやB」+ です・だ・が・を・に etc.
>   「AとかB」+ です・だ・が・を・に etc. ← casual

But not

> ×「AやB**や**」+ です・だ・が・を・に etc.
>   ×「A**など**Bなど」+ です・だ・が・を・に etc.
>   ×「A**など**B」+ です・だ・が・を・に etc.

Comment: Is there any difference in sense between AとかBなど and AとかBとか?

Comment: I think AとかBとか and AやBなど are more common than AとかBなど. To me, AとかBなどです sounds a bit more formal than AとかBとかです and a bit more casual than AやBなどです.

Comment: Btw, this page might be of some help: [How to use とか](http://maggiesensei.com/2015/02/19/how-to-use-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8B-toka/)