# Ordering of Particles:「にや」OR「やに」?

Tags: particle-に, particle-で, particle-や

Does the particle や come after particles like に or で (as does も in「にも」or「でも」), or does it come before them?  I can't find any examples of either, be it through Google; in the Tatoeba database; or otherwise.

Comment: What definition of や are you using?

Comment: As in "AやBや…" meaning "A,B,… and others."

Comment: in that usage, pretty sure your question is moot. That や links nouns or noun/gerund phrases. I can't even imagine why you would want to group other particles with it...  Are you talking about leaving a final や hanging at the end, and whether a particle should come before or after that one??

Comment: Yes, as in using the nouns grouped with や, in a postpositional phrase.  The context that prompted me to ask this question currently was to use some order of「一等親」「や」「に」to say "among immediate family members etc." (and by extension, "among close family and friends"), about nicknames resulting from babytalk pronunciation of one's name.  I've had this question before for other contexts, but I only today got around to asking aloud.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [とか and など in same sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/28716/%e3%81%a8%e3%81%8b-and-%e3%81%aa%e3%81%a9-in-same-sentence)

Answer (score 1):

や in the sense that you are using it, is a linking particle between 2 or more nouns, and cannot be left "hanging" after a noun or noun phrase, so you would not have to worry about how to connect it to other particles.

If you want to imply "etc." or "and others", "and so on" after a single noun or noun phrase, then **など** (or などなど) would be more grammatical. Depending on the circumstances, とか might also be acceptable.

YES: 一等親**や**友達には
YES: 一等親**や**友達**など**には
YES: 一等親**などなど**(の関係人)には
NO: 一等親**や**には

Answer (score 1):

You would expect very little possibility to see the coordinative や and the case particle に next to each other.

や factors out the shortest different sections, so you will find [particle]+や in a `XやY` composition that *X* and *Y* ends in different particles.

> {東京**や**仙台]*から*来た人 (diff. nouns w/ same particle)
>
> 在籍期間が[2012年*まで*‌**や**2018年*から*]の人 (diff. nouns w/ diff. particles)

That means the theoretical order would be にや, but in reality, you will be not likely to encounter such a situation, because に is one of central case marker in Japanese, and や stricter about syntactic leanness than its kinds* (such as か, とか and やら), which means, you need another particle, that is different than に but compared to に, to make something like にや appear. That would result in a very terrible type of [zeugma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma_and_syllepsis), like conjoining subject and object together.

---

* cf.

> [じぶんがいじめられたら先生*に*‌**とか**ともだち*に*そうだんする。](http://www.nhk.or.jp/ijimezero/sengen_school/kantou/11_91.html)
> × 先生*に*‌**や**ともだち*に*そうだんする。