# Difference between など and とか

Tags: word-choice

It seems that など and とか mean "such as" or etc.

what is the difference? can someone give an example sentence?

Thank you!

Comment: i believe this has been answered already here: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/28716/%e3%81%a8%e3%81%8b-and-%e3%81%aa%e3%81%a9-in-same-sentence